# multiple file upload from postman in laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload, postman

I am trying to upload multiple files but I only get 1 file in return.Below is my code:

```
public function uploadQuoteItemImage(){
 $file=Input::file('filename');

 $file_count=count($file);
  dd($file_count);
$uploadcount=0;

foreach($file as $f){
 $random_name=str_random(8);
 $destinationPath='images/';
 $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

 $filename=$random_name.'_quote_itm_image.'.$extension;  
 $byte=File::size($file); //get size of file

 $uploadSuccess=Input::file('filename')->move($destinationPath,$filename);
 $uploadcount ++;

}
if ($uploadcount == $file_count){
 QuoteItemImage::create(array(
     'quote_item_id'=>Input::get('quote_item_id'),
     'filename'=>$filename,
    'filesize'=>$byte
     ));
 return Common::getJsonResponse(true, 'image created', 200);
    }
}
```

[image]
Even though I sent 3 files its returning only 1 file. Please help.

Comment: Is your file input name array (*name[]*)? eg. `<input type="file" name="filename[]" multiple>`

Answer (score 3):

so in the form-data of postman you are giving the key attribute as filename for files 
in turn it should be `filename[]` since you are sending array of data 
once you set it it works fine .

now you can check in the php code like below

```
$files = Input::file('filename');
foreach ($files as $one) {
   $filename       = $one->getClientOriginalName();
   $listfilenames[] = $filename;
                }
echo $listfilenames
```

Comment: The important point here is the name of the request parameter that holds files. It should be `paramName[]`, ending with open and close square brackets.